# Required Field but its allowing empty in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have problem with yii-CJuiAutoComplete. required field is not working for only one field. added required rule in the model.but its not working. its my _form.php

```
    <div class="form-group">
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'collegename',array('class'=>'col-sm-3 control-label')); ?>

<div class="col-sm-9">
   <?php 
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
   'model'=>$form,
   'name'=>'collegename',
   'source'=>$this->createUrl('controller/action'),
   // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
   'options'=>array(
       'showAnim'=>'fold',

   ),
   'htmlOptions'=>array(
      // 'style'=>'height:20px;',
       'class'=>'span5 form-control',
       'placeholder'=>'College Name',
       //'style' => 'text-transform: uppercase'
   ),
 )); 
 ?>
 <?php echo $form->error($model,'collegename'); ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

model

```
array('collegename', 'required'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the form instead of the model.
Try:

```
<?php 
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(

   'model'=>$model,

   'attribute'=>'collegename',

   'source'=>$this->createUrl('controller/action'),
   // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
   'options'=>array(
       'showAnim'=>'fold',

   ),
   'htmlOptions'=>array(
      // 'style'=>'height:20px;',
       'class'=>'span5 form-control',
       'placeholder'=>'College Name',
       //'style' => 'text-transform: uppercase'
   ),
 )); 
 ?>
```

Comment: its showing error in errorSummary but values are submitting... I'm getting this array.....................


`Array
(
    [SdcApplication] => Array
        (
            [eamcetcode] => aaaa
            [district] => 7
            [address] => Guntur
            [spocname] => name
            [spocmail] => something@gmail.com
            [spocmobile] => 9999999999
            [accept] => 1
        )
    [collegename] => 
    [yt0] => 
)`

Comment: Sorry, replace 'name' with 'attribute' and try again. I think it will be ok now.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiInputWidget#attribute-detail

Comment: You are welcome! Why don't you try the Yii 2 ? I can assure you that it's even better.